# Floating text around image in a nested floated div with negative margins

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to float some text in a div around an image, which is itself contained in a div that is floated. The containing div uses negative margins and padding to push `#book3` down.  This seems to affect the image in the `#content-body-text` by shifting it down.

How do I get the picture to be at the top of `#content-body-text`, have the text wrap around the picture and still have `#book3` aligned at the bottom.

Why does the image element behave this way?  It seems like the text behaves as expected and with regard to the negative margin and padding of `#content-body-text` and `#content-body-container`, but the image behaves differently.

If someone has an approach that does not use negative margins, I am up for hearing that as well.

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agola/z9p0t1xc/)

```
<style>
html {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffb83d;
    margin: 0;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.float-left {
    float:left;
}

.float-right {
    float:right;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#content {
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#content-body-container {
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
    top: 28px;
    width: 495px;
    height: 345px;
    padding-top: 117px; /* height of content-body-container - book3 (462-345) - however we subtract out 117 from 462 because of the padding*/
}

#content-body-text {
    margin-top: -117px; /* dead space above book 3 so we can shift up*/
    font-size: 1.1em;

    /* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height: 462px; 
}

/* books and book links */
div.book {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0;
}

a.navlink {
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=60)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.6);
    opacity:.60; 
}

a.navlink:hover {
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=1.0);
    opacity:1.0; 
}

a.book {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#book1 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    top: 61px;
    height: 429px;
    width: 79px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background-color: #ffd48b;
}

#book2 {
    top: 28px;
    height: 462px;
    width: 28px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    background-color: #ffc664;
}

#book3 {
    font-size: .85em;
    height: 345px;
    width: 88px;
    background-color: #ffe3b1;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#book4 {
    font-size: 3.0em;
    top: 40px;
    width: 227px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: Transparent;

    /*/content/images/diag-book.gif*/
    background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,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');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}

#book5{
    width: 93px;
    height: 525px;
    background-color: #ffe3b1;
    margin-top: -35px;
}

a#contact {
    bottom: 54px;
}

a#testimonials {
    bottom: 16px;
}

a#bio {
    margin-left: -65px;
    bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); /* Chrome & Safari */
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);     /* IE 9+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(20deg);      /* Opera */
    transform: rotate(20deg);         /* CSS3 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.93969262, M12=-0.34202014, M21=0.34202014, M22=0.93969262, sizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE 7-8 */
}
</style>

<div id="content-body">

    <div id="book1" class="book">
        <a href="#" id="contact" class="book navlink">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="book2" class="book"></div>

    <div id="content-body-container">
        <div id="book3" class="book">
            <a href="#" id="testimonials" class="book navlink">Testimonials</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-body-text">

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>

            <div style="margin-left:80px;">
                <img id="shifted-down" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41gFs8gGmeL.jpg" width="75" height="100" alt="Image" style="padding-right: 10px; text-align:left; margin-top: -50px; float:left;" />
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut tincidunt turpis. Nulla ultricies suscipit mauris, et viverra lorem vestibulum ac. Sed posuere augue sit amet porttitor condimentum. Nulla eu dolor in purus ullamcorper porta ut suscipit risus.  
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="book4" class="book">
            <a href="#" id="bio" class="bio navlink">Testimonials</a>
    </div>
    <div id="book5" class="book"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your negative margin (you should paste your code in the question). See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gjmkaoph/

Here's what I have changed for both the padding and margin for the elements respectively :

```
#content-body-container {
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
    top: 28px;
    width: 495px;
    height: 345px;
    padding-top: 60px; /* <-- Modified. height of content-body-container - book3 (462-345) - however we subtract out 117 from 462 because of the padding*/
}

#content-body-text {
    margin-top: -60px; /* <-- Modified. dead space above book 3 so we can shift up*/
    font-size: 1.1em;

    /* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height: 462px; 
}
```

You can fine-tune the alignment by yourself, but negative margins are not the 'recommended' way of doing things if you don't want problems like this.

Comment: This will also shift `#book3` up, which is not what I want to do.  The negative margin is used to push `#book3` down to the bottom.

Comment: Why don't you add margin-top to `#book3`? As I've said, using negative margin is prone to giving problems like what you have there.